# Issues with new install SDL Web 8.5

Tags: web8.5, installation, sql-server

We have a new (empty) installation of SDL Web 8.5 CM which is not responding as expected. The CME GUI loads in the browser, but many actions are timing out. Every time we try to make a new publication it times out, and it seems like the first time certain other actions are executed (creating a User or Multimedia MIME type) there is also a time out.

To be sure it was not a network/database connection issue, we have increased the timeouts to 10 minutes for database en core service, and even moved the database onto the same machine as the CM server, but we still see the same issues. The database we are using is (temporarily) MS SQL Server 2016 SP1 Developer edition - not officially supported by SDL but as far as I am aware no different to Standard/Enterprise except for the licensing.

Initially it seemed like the [old MSDTC issue](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/q/8516/54), however as far as I am aware this is no longer relevant for Web 8.5. We got DtcPing to work in any case...

**UPDATE**: After increasing the timeout further, it was possible to create a first publication, and afterwards publications and other items could be created just fine without any delays or timeouts.

When the timeout time is reached, the other error in the event log is:

```
The operation is not valid for the state of the transaction.
StackTrace Information Details:
   at System.Transactions.TransactionState.EnlistPromotableSinglePhase(InternalTransaction tx, IPromotableSinglePhaseNotification promotableSinglePhaseNotification, Transaction atomicTransaction, Guid promoterType)
   at System.Transactions.Transaction.EnlistPromotableSinglePhase(IPromotableSinglePhaseNotification promotableSinglePhaseNotification, Guid promoterType)
   at System.Transactions.Transaction.EnlistPromotableSinglePhase(IPromotableSinglePhaseNotification promotableSinglePhaseNotification)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.EnlistNonNull(Transaction tx)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.Enlist(Transaction tx)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.ActivateConnection(Transaction transaction)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.PrepareConnection(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionInternal obj, Transaction transaction)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Data.AdoNet.DatabaseUtilities.GetConnection()
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Data.AdoNet.DatabaseUtilities.ExecuteReader(StoredProcedureInvocation storedProcedureInvocation, Nullable`1 commandBehavior)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Data.AdoNet.ContentManagement.OrganizationalItemDataMapper.Tridion.ContentManager.Data.ContentManagement.IOrganizationalItemDataMapper.GetUniquenessConflicts(TcmUri orgItemId, ItemType itemType, IEnumerable`1 properties)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement.RepositoryLocalObject.GetConflicts(IEnumerable`1 values, Boolean ignoreSelfConflicts, Repository contextRepository, OrganizationalItem organizationalItem)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement.RepositoryLocalObject.AssertNoUniquenessConflicts(IEnumerable`1 propertiesToCheck, Boolean ignoreSelfConflicts, Action`1 reactOnError)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement.RepositoryLocalObject.AssertNoUniquenessConflicts(IEnumerable`1 propertiesToCheck, Action`1 reactOnError)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement.RepositoryLocalObject.OnSaving(SaveEventArgs eventArgs)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement.VersionedItem.OnSaving(SaveEventArgs eventArgs)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.CommunicationManagement.Template.OnSaving(SaveEventArgs eventArgs)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.IdentifiableObject.Save(SaveEventArgs eventArgs)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement.VersionedItem.Save(Boolean checkInAfterSave)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Templates.SetupDefaultTemplates.CreateOrUpdateTbbWithTextContents(String title, Schema parameterSchema, String content, String templateType)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Templates.SetupDefaultTemplates.CreateOrUpdateCSharpTemplate(TemplateClassInfo classInfo, TemplateAssemblyInfo assemblyInfo)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Templates.SetupDefaultTemplates.SetupCSharpTemplates(XmlNode setupScript, IDictionary`2 loadedAssemblies, IDictionary`2 createdTemplates)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Templates.SetupDefaultTemplates.SetupTemplates(String parentFolderUri, String folderName)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Templates.SetupDefaultTemplates.CreateDefaultTemplates(Session session, String parentFolderUriString, String folderName)
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.RuntimeType.InvokeMember(String name, BindingFlags bindingFlags, Binder binder, Object target, Object[] providedArgs, ParameterModifier[] modifiers, CultureInfo culture, String[] namedParams)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.CommunicationManagement.Publication.CreateDefaultTemplates()
   at Tridion.ContentManager.CommunicationManagement.Publication.OnSaved(SaveEventArgs eventArgs)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.IdentifiableObject.Save(SaveEventArgs eventArgs)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.IdentifiableObject.Save()
   at Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.CoreServiceBase.Create(IdentifiableObjectData data, ReadOptions readBackOptions)
   at SyncInvokeCreate(Object , Object[] , Object[] )
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.CoreServiceInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage11(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)
```

Comment: Can you provide us little more background info about the issue either via screenshots of browser console of CME or any useful trace from eventviewer/sdlweb logs

Comment: I never saw this issue before, but still, I would recommend you to double check your prerequisites, loop back, firewall settings if any, also check the core services web.Configs/services config on the bin folder sometime instead of  localhost may be updated with cms custom domain name may be not resolving on cms server

Comment: What is the question, exactly?

Comment: Please contact sdl support with event log.